# Confused file path notations on multiproject solution

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In my IndexJson.cshtml i have a script notation with src tag:

```
<script src="~/js/site.js"></script>
```

But it reads from my Main's project site.js noted with number 2 on my image , instead of reading from site.js number 1.

[image]

Comment: Is this ASP.net?

Comment: Its .net core mvc

Comment: I do not know how using multiple solutions in asp.net works, but from searching, it looks the the tilde could be partially responsible. If you know the exact url that the specific file would be found at, try replacing the tilde, then go from there.

Comment: I don't think this gonna work. There will be conflict with routing same name files.1 webapp should have 1 wwwroot.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your issue here but I failed. The issue only happens once when setting project1 as the reference project of project2 and run the project2. Here is the screenshot of my test, which I didn't invoke the mysite.js file(***project2***) in project2, but invoke the mysite.js file(***project1***) in project1. When call the web page from project1, instead of getting the js file in Project1, it will get the project2's file:
[image]

Also I think you can use the absolute path of js file to fix the issue:

```
<script src="https://localhost:7175/js/mysite.js"></script>
```